# Eclipse Aptana Python - __name__ undefined variable

Tags: python, eclipse, aptana

I am running into a strange error. I am running Eclipse Kepler with the Aptana Studio plugin. I have recently updated the plugin from 3.4 to version 3.6, which changed the Aptana Pydev version from 2.7 to 3.0. So now my Python 2.7 scripts are not working anymore.

Example:

```
    from scipy.stats import itemfreq        

    def main():
        print 'HelloWorld'

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

This already won't run because __name__ is marked as not defined and itemfreq as unresolved import.

I have Python 2.7 installed via Macports. I double-checked all settings. PYTONPATH, PATH are set to the correct directories. "which python" gives me the right version. I can run the program in a terminal without any errors. In the PyDev Interpreter settings the right location is set and the System PYTHONPATH contains all relevant folders.

I have another Mac where I have basically the same setup and it works like a charm. The only difference is that I didn't update Aptana Studio.

So, anyone an idea what's going on? Do I need to downgrade Aptana Studio again? Are there any settings I did not mention? If you have any more questions to clarify the situation, please ask!

Any help is appreciated! Thx!

*edited the Aptana Studio plugin versions

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue at the moment:
 [Aptana stand-alone 3.6.0 pydev not working properly Mac 10.8.5 #223](https://github.com/aptana/studio3/issues/223)

In my case, I use Win 8.1 Pro x64, but I had the same issues, so, I removed the 3.6.0 update, and installed an older 3.4.2

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but I encountered this same problem with Aptana 3.6 today and still haven't found a solution. But I did find a passable workaround that will catch lots of the recurring unnecessary error flags.

Window->Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Code Analysis->Undefined (Tab)

Then in the Box that says "consider the following names as globals", enter in _ name _ etc. I had to enter dict, super, True, False, object. Obviously it's a workaround but it does catch most of the errors without ignoring everything.

Comment: I know, I have since gone back to using PyDev. But if this is what you're doing, here was my current list before switching back:
all,and,any,as,assert,break,class,continue,def,del,dict,elif,else,except,exec,False,finally,for,from,global,if,import,in,is,len,lambda,map,None,not,or,pass,print,raise,return,super,True,try,tuple,unicode,while,with,yield,isinstance,hasattr

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve the original problem, but using a workaround now to being able to work.

The workaround I am now using is that I just installed the standalone PyDev plugin in its latest version (3.6). Now the scripts are running again without any other changes.

Unfortunately the Aptana studio plugin was removed in the process. Therefore I would still appreciate a solution to the original question. Thx.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the update. I have also just updated Aptana studio to 3.6 on win8 and none of the built-ins resolve anymore in the code analysis but the code still runs fine. Perhaps there will be a hotfix in the future...